# Angular2 value one way binding

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

In Angular, how can I have the hero name *(first div/I want a fix name)* not change when I write a new hero name (value) in the input element?

```
<div>I want a fix name: {{hero.name}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name:
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
  </label>
</div>
```

I believe the "technique" is called one-way binding, but I don't seem to find how to accomplish this exact scenario.

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I didn't understand that _"syntax [target]=expression is a one way data binding_" is referring to the input element. I thought the bind needed to be defined in the div element, because what if, for example, I just want to bind just one element instead of all in the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `[ngModel]` for one way binding

```
<input [ngModel]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
```

Comment: Thank you @SachilaRanawaka. I understand my confusion now. I was not expecting it to be in the <input> but rather in the <div>.
What if, for example, I just want to bind one element instead of all in the page?